# How to get class name of String object?

Tags: freemarker

I set a bean's property to a String object, then when I try to get the class name of the property ,below error is thrown out:

> Expected hash. plist[0].javaType evaluated instead to freemarker.template.SimpleScalar on line 7, column 26 in ibatis/macro.ftl.

template code is as below:

```
<#assign clsName=plist[0].javaType.class.name>
```

When property javaType is set to  a java bean, class name can be properly got.  Why is it? I need the property could be given any type, java bean ,non java bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the issue here is that FreeMarker doesn't work with Java values/objects directly. The template language has its own simple type-system, and stuff coming from outside is mapped to that through a technique called object-wrapping. (Values that doesn't come from outside doesn't even have a wrapped object inside.) That you was still able to get the class of some object is purely accidental... What happens is that the object-wrapping machinery decides that the object should be mapped to the "hash" FreeMarker type, and the hash items will correspond to the JavaBean properties of the objects. The object has a `getClass()` method, which is (mistakenly) seen as the getter of the "class" property.

So there's no universal way of getting the class... among others because sometimes there's no class to get. You could write a `TemplateMethodModelEx` that does a good enough effort to do so.

Comment: You mean implementing TemplateMethodModelEx's exec method which works like a freemarker function? It's strange to hear fm can't get all class name naturally , after all it's coded in java, works with java, and has a lot of functions(methods) of java.

Comment: The template language is *implemented* in Java, but doesn't use Java types/classes. Like if you have a string, you don't have `.length()`. That's because you may expose non-String Java objects as a string, and that should remain transparent. Anyway, you can still make an effort to get the class name (see if the value implements `TemplateModelAdapter`, etc.), which is possibly good enough for your particular application, but there's no solution that works on every place where FM is used. Hence there's nothing in the template language for this.

Comment: Hi ddekany, could you pls give me an sample on how to determine the value implements TemplateModelAdapter? Thanks.

Comment: This functionality is something that you should implement with `TemplateMethodModelEx`, as I said earlier. Thus you implement this function in Java, where of course can use `instanceof`.